# Joining multiple excel defined name range (including pivot tables) in one pivot table

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, pivot

I hope someone can answer the following question.

This is the scenario:
In Sheet1 I have a Pivot table from ColumnA to columnC with formulas running from ColumnD to ColumnZ.
Sheet2 has a Pivot table from ColumnA to ColumnE with formulas running from ColumnF to ColumnL

For both sheets I have created a dynamic name range called: Sheet1FullTable (Pivot+Formulas) and Sheet2FullTable

Both dynamic ranges have in common 1 field which is my "keyID"

Is there a way I can merge the 2 Dynamic ranges into a Pivot Table?
Or a way to query data out of the 2 dynamic range which I can later use for a pivot table?

Thank you,

Comment: What I am supposed to do with that? I doubt I can merge both tables that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use Name Manager to create a new named range with existing named ranges:

- Go to "Name Manager" (ctrl-F3)
- Click New...
- Name your range
- Refers to `=namedrange1,namedrange2,etc`

Comment: I did it but I cannot create a pivot table out of it. It seems to be a name range which I can't actually use as intended

Comment: How do you feel about using a VBA solution?

Comment: I will test any solution, I thought PowerQuery would have been the optimal one but I would give VBA a shot.